# Javascript Button SRC

Tags: javascript, html

i need some help on **JavaScript img src** and **click event.**

Lets say i have a 2 images of button, p**ressed and unpressed.**

```
btn1_On = new Image();
btn1_On.src = "../img/numpad/03_Button_1_Push.jpg";

btn1_Off = new Image();
btn1_Off.src = "../img/numpad/03_Button_1_No_Push.jpg";
```

**and html:**

```
<div class="Numpad_1" onmousedown="btnPress('btn1');return true;"
    onmouseup="btnRelease('btn1');return true;"
    onclick="btnPress('btn1');return true;">
    <img src="..\img\numpad\03_Button_1_No_Push.jpg" id="btn1" />
</div>
```

i don`t want to multiply function for each button in **html**, so i create function to **press btn** and **release**:

```
function btnPress(btn) {
    document.getElementById(btn).src = btn+'_On'.src;
}

function btnRelease(btn) {
    document.getElementById(btn).src = btn + '_Off.src';
}
```

so, a problem is, btn+'_On'.src - cant init the path of
image(undefined).

Thnx for any HELP.

**P.S: I have some limitation , it must run on IE 6**

Comment: Side Note: Stop supporting IE9< browsers

Comment: If you only wanna store the path of the images, then you don't need the `Image` objects. You can just store the text as string.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen, OP must be using it to preload the images, if not you suggestion is valid.

Comment: Yes you're right @Satpal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created object `btn1_On` in window/global context, then you  use

```
document.getElementById(btn).src = window[btn+'_On'].src;
```

---

However, I would recommend to create a object, and then access the properties

```
var obj = {};
obj.btn1_On = new Image();
obj.btn1_Off = new Image();
```

Use Bracket notation to get properties based on string.

```
document.getElementById(btn).src = obj[btn+'_On'].src;
```

Comment: Great, thnx, but why create the object is recomended?

Comment: @Aleksey, I will be much easier to maintain and debug and performance wise much better